# Transparent collapsible with jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone tell me if this coding is correct? Ran with http://www.css-validator.org/validator but says:

```
Sorry! We found the following errors (3)
URI : TextArea
4   .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn     Property text-shadow doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in : none none
5   .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn     Value Error : background Too many values or values are not recognized : rgba(255,255,255,0.1) rgba(255,255,255,0.1)
9   .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn     Parse Error [empty string] .
```

html code is:

```html
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="col">

  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" class="ui-nodisc-icon">
    <h3>Breakfast</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" class="ui-nodisc-icon">
    <h3>Tacos</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

in css:

```css
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn {
  font-family: 'CaviarDreams';
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00ffff;
  color: #00ffff;
}
```

Sample page: http://cjoes.site50.net/#menu

Answer (score 0):

You are using CSS3 functionality, so when you run the CSS validater, you should choose CSS3, under 'More options'.

Comment: thnx alot!  this time ran it with  css3 option and returned no errors